# pagination links not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on pagination in codeigniter using ajax , I have problem with pagination links, if I click on second link then url will change but there is no data load on second page and also showing active first link with second link.

my controller function from star.php

```
public function filtersearch()
    {
        $proSearch = implode(",", $_POST['search']) ;

        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        log_message('error', 'post value is  '.$proSearch );
        log_message('error', '  '.$cat );
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = "#";
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Star_model->getfilterCount($proSearch,$cat);
        $config["per_page"] = 2;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
         $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '«';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '»';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $offset = $this->input->get('offset');
         $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
             $output = array(
                'pagination_link'  => $this->pagination->create_links(),
                 'country_table'   => $this->Star_model->getfilterSearch($proSearch,$cat,$config["per_page"],$offset)
                 );

             $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');

             echo json_encode($output);
            }

    }
```

and  view page products.php coding for send input for getdata through ajax

```
$(".cl").live("click", function () {
var val = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();

        var cat = $("#sub_cat").val();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>star/filtersearch",
            data: {search: val, cat: cat},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
           $("#asd").hide();
            $('#country_table').html(data.country_table);
            $('#pagination_link').html(data.pagination_link);

        }
        });

    });
```

here is coding of getting data after click on link

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function load_data(page)
 {
    var val = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();

        var cat = $("#sub_cat").val();
        alert(val+cat);
    $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>star/filtersearch",
   method:"POST",
   data: {search: val, cat: cat},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {

    $('#country_table').html(data.country_table);
    $('#pagination_link').html(data.pagination_link);
    $("#asd").hide();
   }
  });

 }
  load_data(1);

  $(".pagination li a").live("click", function () {
       var cur_page = $(this).attr('data-ci-pagination-page'); // I haved test with attr('href') but not ok.
               load_data(cur_page);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

set your base url as the current URL of the page where you are applying the pagination

```
$config["base_url"] = "#";
```

eg: `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . 'user/index';`

Try This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567423/how-to-show-ajax-pagination-data-without-refresh-or-reload-a-page-in-codeigniter) for example

Comment: after this my page is refreshing and i cant show my result data. I don't want to refresh page

Comment: i have used ajax already, but how can i get resultant data without page refresh or with page refresh.

Comment: try insert `$page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $start = ($page - 1) * $config["per_page"];`  after `$this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;`

Comment: Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-2' at line 1 - Invalid query: SELECT * from sf_products WHERE sub_cat_id = '12' LIMIT 2   -2...................I got this error in my query